# Arch Linux - KiCad Spice netlist generation fails when using a pulsed voltage source

Tags: kicad

I'm new to KiCad and I'm trying to simulate a simple circuit:

[image]

This works fine. The simulation tool works, and if I generate the netlist for spice and can see no problem:

[image]

Works like a charm.
But now I try to edit the voltage model, just like this:

[image]

Now the simulation fails, and if I generate the netlist I can see that it is wrong! The voltage source is not connected as in the schematic:

[image]

The Net-_R1-Pad2_0 is missing! Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: KiCad forum: https://forum.kicad.info/t/kicad-spice-netlist-generation-fails-when-using-a-pulsed-voltage-source/16482

Comment: KiCad bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/kicad/+bug/1825818

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is cross-posting. If the problem is with KiCAD the KiCAD forum is the best place

Comment: @JonRB I thought other people might have this same question. It is not straight forward to know whether this is a bug or if the user is doing something wrong.

Comment: but this isn't a forum. This is a Q&A site. On the basis that you have received replies from the KiCAD people this could be a bug why are you posting here?  in fact I have just reproduced this in KiCAD-5.1 on GentooLinux and it works so this is probably an ArchLinux and how they mess with libraries. Please raise a bug with Archlinux

Comment: I posted it first here because in the beginning I didn't know it was a bug... I thought I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: @JonRB This q&a section has a tag for program specific questions. This will naturally lead to users making support questions here. Which can include bugs as well as misunderstandings. So either remove all program specific questions or accept that such questions will come from time to time. (pointing to the forum is however valid as it is faster to get answers there in most cases.)

Comment: @RenePöschl I am aware of that... and I have provided program specific help a few times. The user has already recieved replied from the kicad forum. Equally on the kicad forum a windows user said it works. Likewise as a gentoo user this works. This is a distro-specific query of a KiCAD bug, thus does not belong here

Comment: @JonRB and how should the user or anybody else know that before getting an answer? Again as long as you have program specific tags you will get such inquiries as users typically can not tell if their question is the result of a bug or a mistake they made.

Comment: @RenePöschl except... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/is-cross-posting-wrong-to-an-external-site this was a cross-post on essentially the same day. KiCAD forum && EE.SE. && launchpad. This is my concern ... there was no reasonable time in one domain before posting in another.  If you have a problem with that please take it up with the meta.  Cross posting of SE is highly frownd upon and cross-posting domains, while not as bad, isn't advocated. There was a reply on the KiCAD forums making bumping this (2days ago by a pointless edit) even odder